# Visual Basic 6 ADO update sql string

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb, recordset

I am trying to update a single record in sql using a recordset I'm Pulling data from one recordset and trying to save it to another table in the database This is the code I have the insert statement runs fine in SQL.

```vb
' Opening the connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=" & dbLocation & "; Initial Catalog=Posbdat; User Id=sa"
cn.Open
rh.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=" & dbLocation & "; Initial Catalog=Postrans; User Id=sa"
rh.Open

 rs.Open "Select Top 1 * from CustomerPoints order by RedemptionDate desc", cn, adModeReadWrite
x.Open " Select Top 1 * from Register_Header order by datetime desc", rh, adModeReadWrite

rt.Open " SELECT top 1 upc FROM   Register_Trans INNER JOIN Register_Header ON Register_Trans.trans_no = Register_Header.trans_no Where trans_subtype  = 'AP' Order by Register_Trans.datetime desc ", rh, adOpenDynamic

Debug.Print x!emp_no
 Debug.Print x!till_no
 Debug.Print x.Fields(10)
 Debug.Print itemupc
itemupc = rt.Fields(0)
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Recordset
 cmd.Open "UPDATE CustomerPoints set emp_no = " & x!emp_no & _
 ", till_no = " & x!till_no & " purch_amt = " & x!Total & _
 ", item_redeem = ' " & itemupc & " ' Where RedemptionDate = (Select top 1 * from CustomerPoints order by " & _
 "RedemptionDate Desc)", cn, adOpenDynamic
cmd.update
```

I haven't closed any of the connections or cleaned it up because it won't run without crashing.

Comment: And the error you get is ...?

Comment: 5/7/2013 10:35:40 AM        End_Trans 23  3251 ADODB.Recordset Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype.
dbEngineErr : No current record.

Comment: Again it has been a long time but when you perform an cmd.UPDATE it assumes you have a recordset loaded that you have modified and then are saving back.  The method you are trying to use requires you SELECT an updatable recordset, make your changes cmd!emp_no = x!emp_no then cmd.UPDATE.  You have an empty recordset, made no changes, and tried to update your NULL record set.  The post I made shows you how to just execute the SQL instead of loading a recordset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a long time but this is how I used to execute update statements:

```
Dim conTemp As New ADODB.Connection

conTemp.CommandTimeout = mvarconConnection.CommandTimeout
conTemp.ConnectionTimeout = mvarconConnection.ConnectionTimeout
conTemp.CursorLocation = mvarconConnection.CursorLocation
conTemp.Mode = mvarconConnection.Mode
conTemp.ConnectionString = mvarconConnection.ConnectionString
conTemp.Open mvarconConnection.ConnectionString

conTemp.Execute "SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF"

conTemp.Execute "UPDATE CustomerPoints set emp_no = " & x!emp_no & _
", till_no = " & x!till_no & " purch_amt = " & x!Total & _
", item_redeem = ' " & itemupc & " ' Where RedemptionDate = (Select top 1 * from
CustomerPoints order by " & _
"RedemptionDate Desc)"
```

The mvarconConnection is just an object that stored all of my DB settings, just replace my settings with your own.